# Can clustering be implemented as Linear Programming?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, matlab, integer-programming, clustering

When considering Gaussian mixture models (GMM) one efficient algorithm is the Expectation-Minimization (EM) algorithm. The E-step famously determines the degree of membership.

For example, given a GMM with two Gaussians (normal distributions) $N_1,N_2$ and a dataset $X$ of samples, the E-step will try to determine, provide a probability, if a given sample $x_s$ has been sampled from $N_1$ or from $N_2$.

**Can the E-step be substituted with some form of (integer) linear programming?**

I have seen references such as this [http://imagine.enpc.fr/~komodakn/publications/docs/NIPS09_clustering.pdf](http://imagine.enpc.fr/%7Ekomodakn/publications/docs/NIPS09_clustering.pdf) but I cannot find a direct and simple way to fomrulate this problem easily in say MATLAB.

Any references would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see the benefit of doing so. Why not just estimate a real distribution and then regularize and truncate it (if needed)?

Comment: Not sure I follow. Basically, one of the reasons is you can do robust estimation eventually. So yeah, my questions is how exactly one can implement it.

Comment: I think integer programming in this area is like walking over 10 bridges to get water.

Comment: Do you know some other way to do robust parameter estimation?

Comment: Sure. But I can't refer to it yet, because no book has been written about it. I can write a short answer later if you want me to.

Comment: Please feel free so. I am also aware of some work by e.g. Kothari but I am curious as to what you refer to.